# Store image in database and retrieve it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

My code for inserting image in database is as follows:

```
MemoryStream ms =new MemoryStream();
byte[] PhotoByte=null;
PhotoByte=ms.ToArray();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
PhotoByte =ms.ToArray();
Str = "insert into Experimmm Values('" + PhotoByte + "','" + textBox1.Text + "')";
Conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = Conn;
cmd.CommandText = Str;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Conn.Close();
```

Which is going well. I can see binary data in ma database table like `<Binary Data>`
My code for retrieving data is:

```
Str ="select * from Experimmm where id = '" +textBox2.Text + "'";
Conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = Conn;
cmd.CommandText = Str;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{ label1.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
byte[] PhotoByte = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(PhotoByte, 0, PhotoByte.Length);
//but an error takes place on next line "Parameter is not valid."             
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
} Conn.Close();
```

I'm using visual studio 10 , C# ,sql server 2005

Comment: PLZ Store paths rather then images - then you won't be needing all of this.

Comment: _which_ parameter is not valid? Please post the entire exception instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: sir i have to store images because i want to use them in crystal report dynamically... 
thanx JonH for such a fast reply

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285213/parameter-is-not-valid-error-when-creating-image-from-byte-in-c-sharp

Comment: John Saunders @pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
"mem" is the parameter

Comment: @JonH - Time to read [To BLOB or not to BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525), I think.

Comment: Since it doesn't seem like anyone else has mentioned it, it's time to swap out that string concatenation with a parametrized query.  SQL injections are no fun.

Comment: @Ravi - that question has nothing about databases. Not even close to being a duplicate.

Comment: oooooo tell me what should i do..???

Comment: @Oded.. ah. ! i said possible. nyway :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible of course to store your images in db. However it is not recommended. It is better to store them in a file system.

Your code is a bit messy. The following is a better example.

```
MemoryStream ms =new MemoryStream(); 
byte[] PhotoByte=null; 
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
PhotoByte =ms.ToArray(); 
// I'm not sure whether you are able to create an sql by simply concating the string
Str = "insert into Experimmm Values('@PhotoBytes','@MyTextValue')"; 
// You have to parametrize your query
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PhotoBytes", PhotoByte);
// This also helps you to avoid syntactical corruption in case of ' and sql injection
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MyTextValue", textBox1.Text );
Conn.Open(); 
cmd.Connection = Conn; 
cmd.CommandText = Str; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
Conn.Close();
```

When you retrieve you could use a binary writer in some handler

```
namespace TestNS
{
   public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
      // Override the ProcessRequest method.
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
         // Your preparations, i.e. querystring or something
         var conn = new SqlConnection("Your connectionstring");
         var command = new SqlCommand("Your sql for retrieval of the bytes", conn);
         conn.Open();
         var data = (Byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
         conn.Close();
         context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);      }

      public Boolean IsReusable
      {
         get { return false; }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sir i'm beginner plz forgive me if i'm asking a silly que...
""what is the namespace for context"" an error occurred when i copied the cod

Answer (score 5):

You have several issues with your code. I'll address it line-by-line:

```
MemoryStream ms =new MemoryStream();
byte[] PhotoByte=null;
PhotoByte=ms.ToArray();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
PhotoByte =ms.ToArray();
```

While it's not a problem, you have needless assignments here. The code above could be more clearly written this way:

```
MemoryStream ms =new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] PhotoByte =ms.ToArray();
```

Next, the following code is not using parameters. **Always, always, ALWAYS parameterize your SQL queries instead of dynamically building the SQL. No, seriously, always. Yes, even then.** (Also, what is the `Str` variable? Some sort of reused instance variable? Don't do that.)

```
Str = "insert into Experimmm Values('" + PhotoByte + "','" + textBox1.Text + "')";
Conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = Conn;
cmd.CommandText = Str;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Conn.Close();
```

Instead, it should be this:

```
Conn.Open();
using(SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Experimmm (column list) values(@data, @name)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = PhotoByte;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, yourlength).Value = textBox1.Text;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
Conn.Close();
```

Next, we'll move onto your retrieval. Again with the `Str` variable, don't do this sort of thing. Also, you need to parameterize this query as well.

```
byte[] data;
string name;

Conn.Open();
using(SqlCommand cmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
{    
    cmd.CommandText = "select column_list from Experimmm where id = @id";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, field_length).Value = textBox2.Text;

    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            data = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0); 
            name = (string)dr.GetValue(1);
        }
    }
}
Conn.Close();

label1.Text = name;
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\KUTTY\Real_Project\Royalty_Pro\DbRoyalty_Access\Buzz_Loyalty.mdb");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select pic from test_table where id_image='123'",con);
OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds,"test_table");
//con.Close();

//ds = new DataSet();
//da.Fill(ds, "test_table");
FileStream FS1 = new FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create);
if (ds.Tables["test_table"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    byte[] blob = (byte[])ds.Tables["test_table"].Rows[0]["pic"];
    FS1.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
    FS1.Close();
    FS1 = null;

    byte[] imageData = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);



    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
    pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox2.Refresh();

    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(blob));  
    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
    pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox2.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead of concatenating a SQL string.

Apart from fixing the obvious [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability, this will enable you to properly insert an image into the database.

There are many questions and answers on [how to insert into a SQL Server image/binary field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416881/insert-picture-into-sql-server-2005-image-field-using-only-sql) - you should look at them.