# F# Creating bitmap from a memory stream throwing an exception

Tags: bitmap, f#

I'm getting

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'
```

for some reason.

A line where I'm getting it:

```
let image = Bitmap.FromStream stream
```

That's what I have

```
let ChangeBitmapColors (bitmap : Bitmap) =
Console.WriteLine bitmap.Size

let width = bitmap.Width
let height = bitmap.Height

let rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height)

let bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rectangle, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat)
let length = bitmapData.Stride * height
let bitmapArray : byte[] = Array.zeroCreate length

Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapArray, 0, length)

bitmap.UnlockBits bitmapData

//todo something with bitmapArray

use stream = new MemoryStream(bitmapArray)                                           

let image = Bitmap.FromStream stream

stream.Dispose |> ignore

image
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ildjarn, hey, initialy bitmap.PixelFormat was there, i've tried to use specific pixel format while troubleshooting but got the same exception

Comment: btw, do you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285213/parameter-is-not-valid-error-when-creating-image-from-byte-in-c-sharp

Comment: @FoggyFinder yes, I tried that as well

Comment: okay, next shot - `let image = new Bitmap(width, height, bitmapData.Stride, bitmap.PixelFormat,Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bitmapArray, 0))`

Comment: @d.dizhevskiy I really recommend join to the [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/). Recently was open #ru-general channel (if you prefer russian language)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Okay it helped, thanks. Any ideas why stream didn't work?

Comment: Small thing, but... I don't see the need for the explicit `stream.Dispose` when `use stream` is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why your code not working (I tested it and got the same result).

Another option (that works for me) it's use [Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k4y07x3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
let image = new Bitmap(width, height, bitmapData.Stride, bitmap.PixelFormat,Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bi‌​tmapArray, 0))
```

---

**Edit**

Thanks @ildjarn for the explanation:

> The stream didn't work because it was just raw pixel data without any
>   image header, so there was no way to know simple things like the image
>   dimensions and palette type. The stream approach is possible, but you
>   need to save the image header to the stream, too, not just the
>   scanlines

Comment: The resulting bitmap displays ok.

Comment: anyway I would like to know why stream don't work in that case :(

Comment: @d.dizhevskiy : The stream didn't work because it was just raw pixel data without any image header, so there was no way to know simple things like the image dimensions and palette type. The stream approach is possible, but you need to save the image header to the stream, too, not just the scanlines.