# Error: "Parameter is not valid", when converting byte[] to image

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

So I am trying to convert an array of bytes to an image but I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' The byte[] comes from a database in SQL server where the data type is "image".

I have already tried every solution that I have found offered in other questions in StackOverflow and they have not worked for me; Here is my code:

```
//biblioteca.herramientas is where I make the connection with the server
DataSet dataset_Image;
dataset_Image = Biblioteca.Herramientas(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Image WHERE id_Image = " + 1));

array = (byte[])dataset_Image.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image"];

public byte[] TheImage
{
    set
    {
        theImage = ImageConversor.ByteArrayToImage(value);
        PictureBox2.Image = theImage;
    }
}
```

This is where I have the error:

```
public class ImageConversor
{
    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    { //HERE THE ERROR APPEARS
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
}

The following picture is the SQL table that I am accessing to:
```

[image: SQL table]

And that is all, if you need more info I will share it, thank you for your time, hope you have a good day. (:

**EDIT:**
The code works fine if I add the picture directly from SQLS, changing the column "image"(where the picture is stored) datatype from "image" to "varbinary(MAX)" and then using the following code to insert the image:

```
insert into Image select * from openrowset (bulk N'picture directory', single_blob) as image
```

The problem is that I can not use that to add the picture, but I dont know, maybe it helps to solve this problem :/

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with the image data stored in your database. I have tried code like `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"path\to\an\image.png"); var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes); Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);`, and it works as expected. If, instead, I pass in a random array of bytes, I also get the `ArgumentException` you mentioned. Maybe, you simply have an unsupported image type in your db.

Comment: What format is that image? Have you tried saving it as a file somewhere to see if it *is* a valid image? Maybe the data is corrupt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter is not valid error when creating image from byte\[\] in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285213/parameter-is-not-valid-error-when-creating-image-from-byte-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Have you confirmed your code is getting the entire image, and not just the first X bytes?

Comment: @nollidge I have implemented the solution offered on that page, it still gives me the error. ):

Comment: @Amy I don't know how to check that, but I have created a "foreach" where a string gets every bytes contained in "array =(byte[])dataset_Image.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image"];" and the result is this: "831211151161011096661211161019193". And the value of the image in my table "Image" is "0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D", I don't know if this solves your question, if not you can tell me how te check it and I will do it.

Comment: @JonSkeet The image is in .jpg, I can open it and also If I save the picture with the openrowset structure in the SQL table "Image" giving the column "image" (where the picture is stored) the datatype "varbinary(MAX)" using SQL Server Management Studio, the program works fine and it shows the picture, so I don't think there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: @ChristophHerold How can I see if it is supported or not? I don't know if this helps, but the program works fine if I insert that same picture in the table directly from SQLS changing the column "image" data type from "image" to "varbinary(MAX)" and then using "openrowset (bulk N'', single_blob) as image" when adding it

Comment: I suggest you write the file to disk from the same code that fetches it from the database, so you can then check you can open it in *that* case.